# 2 LocalBusiness schema markups on same location page

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets, microdata, json-ld

We have a company with multiple locations around the U.S. When we built our website we used a Google My Business reviews plugin to dynamically pull in reviews from our Google My Business page. Within this we utilize the rich snippets option and have received the schema snippet on 95% of our location pages. This is great but we are now wanting to implement JSON-LD for local business and highlight multiple sources for our business, i.e. NAP, Service Area, Hours, etc.

The current plugin for reviews utilizes Microdata but we want to implement JSON-LD for the additional schema. Is this possible? Will this hurt us / confuse bots crawling our site? Example codes below:

```html
<div class="wp-gr wpac" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness" style="">
<div class="wp-google-list">
<div class="wp-google-place">
<div class="wp-google-right">
<div class="wp-google-name"> 
<a href="https://maps.google.com/?cid=12545002317743398323" class="" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
<span itemprop="name">Discount Dumpster Rental</span>
</a><meta itemprop="image" content="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png"/></div>
<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating"> 
<span class="wp-google-rating" itemprop="ratingValue">5.0</span> 
<span class="wp-google-stars">
<span class="wp-stars">
<span class="wp-star">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="17" height="17" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792"><path d="M1728 647q0 22-26 48l-363 354 86 500q1 7 1 20 0 21-10.5 35.5t-30.5 14.5q-19 0-40-12l-449-236-449 236q-22 12-40 12-21 0-31.5-14.5t-10.5-35.5q0-6 2-20l86-500-364-354q-25-27-25-48 0-37 56-46l502-73 225-455q19-41 49-41t49 41l225 455 502 73q56 9 56 46z" fill="#e7711b"></path></svg></span>
<span class="wp-star"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="17" height="17" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792"><path d="M1728 647q0 22-26 48l-363 354 86 500q1 7 1 20 0 21-10.5 35.5t-30.5 14.5q-19 0-40-12l-449-236-449 236q-22 12-40 12-21 0-31.5-14.5t-10.5-35.5q0-6 2-20l86-500-364-354q-25-27-25-48 0-37 56-46l502-73 225-455q19-41 49-41t49 41l225 455 502 73q56 9 56 46z"
```

Updated JSON-LD:

```json
{
  "@context": "http://www.schema.org",
  "@type": "LocalBusiness",
  "name": "Business Name",
  "url": "URL",
  "logo": "Logo",
  "image": "Logo",
  "description": "Business Description",
  "priceRange": "$",
  "serviceArea": {
    "@type": "City",
    "name": [Service Areas]
  },
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "",
    "addressLocality": "",
    "addressRegion": "",
    "postalCode": "",
    "addressCountry": "United States"
  },
  "telephone": "",
  "geo": {
    "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
    "latitude": "",
    "longitude": ""
  },
  "hasMap": "Google Maps URL",
  "openingHours": "Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr 08:30-18:00, Sa 08:30-15:30"
  },
  "contactPoint": {
    "@type": "ContactPoint",
    "telephone": "",
    "contactType": "Sales"
  }
```

Thoughts on having both on the same page in different locations? We are worried if we take away the rating schema our rich snippets will not return.

Answer (score 1):

As the moment Google does not merge entities between microdata and json-ld. This means you will have two LocalBusiness entities on the page, and Google will pick one. Google says they prefer you to use json-ld, so it might be that one, without the review stars.

If you marked up both entities in the same syntax, then you can merge them by giving them the same id.